# Image width in XSL-FO generated PDF

Tags: html, xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I've been working on understanding and tweaking some C# code that creates a PDF. The implementation I am understanding has an XSL that transforms the 
near-html text into a XSL-FO, which is then turned into a PDF.

There is an image in a table which is 175 pixels wide and I want it to be left aligned in the top left corner, and take exactly 175 pixels on screen when viewing the pdf file on desktop at 100% zoom (ie. original size).

I have the intermediate XSL-FO but don't know what is wrong with it.

Currently the below XSL-FO generates the pdf where the image (logo-175x45.jpg) is left aligned just fine, but takes up close to 243 pixels on screen

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in" margin-top="0.60in" margin-bottom="0.50in" margin-left="1in" margin-right="1in">
        <fo:region-body margin="0in" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block font-size=".75em">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-column column-width="238pt" />
                <fo:table-column column-width="180pt" />
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-start="1pt" padding-end="1pt" padding-before="1pt" padding-after="1pt">
                            <fo:block text-align="start">
                                <fo:block text-align="start">
                                    <fo:block space-after="12pt">
                                        <fo:external-graphic src="c:\logo-175x45.jpg" width="175px" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-start="1pt" padding-end="1pt" padding-before="1pt" padding-after="1pt">
                            <fo:block text-align="start">
                                <fo:block font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" font-size="2.5em" font-weight="bold" color="#d9d9d9" text-align="end">INVOICE</fo:block>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Also, if you can point me to reading resource on this, it will be great. I'm kind of lost in understanding this myself. I'm new to web programming

Comment: What FO engine are you using? Have you tried rendering the PDF with a different engine?

Comment: The error in your statement is ... and take exactly 175 pixels on screen when viewing the pdf file on desktop at 100% zoom. Whose screen? What resolution is the screen? A "pixel" is a device dependent measurement and cannot be used to set an absolute size (only at its exact time of interpretation and by the interpreter). You want an exact size, use an exact size.

Answer (score 3):

Using pixels is inherently inaccurate.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#pixels

The XSL 1.1 spec doesn't specify the number of pixels in an inch, so different formatters may have different defaults.  Some may let you specify how many pixels in an inch (e.g., https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-optset.html#pxpi).

Some graphic file formats encode their resolution in pixels/inch (or pixels/cm) in the file, and the formatter may be honouring that rather than its own built-in resolution.

Finally, but unlikely for your 175-pixel image, a formatter may be downsampling high-resolution raster images to match its specified output resolution so that output files are smaller and quicker to print/view (e.g., https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-optset.html#color-downsampling).

Then, when you view the PDF, your computer and/or PDF viewer may have a different idea of how many pixels in an inch.  For example, the preferences settings in Acrobat Reader DC allows you to set a custom resolution.

So an XSL-FO formatter with a default 96 pixel/inch `px` unit may render a 175 pixel/72 dpi image as 2.43 inches wide, and a PDF viewer with a resolution of 96 pixel/inch could show the 2.43 inches as 233 pixels at 100% zoom.  Those numbers don't match yours, but they illustrate the sort of things that can go on.

The bottom line is that when you print it, the 175-pixel image will look very grainy anyway.  You would be better off using a vector image or, failing that, a raster image with a resolution matching the resolution of your highest-dpi expected output device and, if your formatter doesn't honour the size or resolution specified in the graphic file, specifying in the FO file the formatted size of the image in inches or some other fixed unit.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [content-width](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xsl-20011015/slice7.html#content-width) attribute to your `fo:external-graphic`:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="c:\logo-175x45.jpg" content-width="175px" width="175px" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it did not resolve the issue. The output PDF looks the same

Comment: I think you should use an exact size at the resolution you desire. If you are dealing with viewing the PDF in a web browser then use 96px/inch and set the content width to 1.822917in.